# Delete alert from TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, alert

I added an alert to TFS2010, that sends an email whenever someone checks in a file in a specific project. The alert works - I receive plenty of emails from the server. I want to remove the alert but cannot find any place to do it. Here is what I tried using VS2010:

- In Team Explorer right click the team project collection -> Alerts Explorer. It shows an empty list. Clicking Refresh makes no difference. Screenshots of what I'm doing:

[image: Right click on team project collection]

[image]

After refresh:

[image]

- In the Team menu click Alerts Explorer. Same result as above.
- In Team Explorer right click the team project -> Project Alerts... It shows "Check the alert you want to create". I don't want to create an alert. None of the items are checked.
- In the Team menu click Project Alerts... Same result as above.
- In Source Control Explorer right click the team project collection -> Alert on Change... It shows "Add Alert to Folder". That is not what I want to do. The same happens when right clicking on the project.
- In Source Control Explorer right click the team project -> Alert on Change... Same result as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that phantom team alerts are a known problem. The solution:

Find the id in tbl_EventSubscription

Run BisSubscribe.exe:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools>bissubscribe /unsubscribe /collection http://mytfsservername:8080/Tfs/DefaultCollection /id 51
```